# Pynput listener doesn't allow if statements with alphanumeric characters

Tags: python, keyboard, keyboard-events, pynput

I'm trying to create a piano keyboard in Python using Jazz-Plugin for sending the MIDI messages and Pynput listener to register the keystrokes.

My problem is that I want the lowest note to be on the Z key. I can't seem to find a way to get my if statement to recognise z, or any other alphanumeric keys when pressed. It DOES work with special keys, such as LCtrl.

I tried to find what data type key was. When key is a special character, the type is `<enum 'Key'>` but when it's an alphanumeric character it is `<class 'pynput.keyboard._win32.KeyCode'>`

This didn't work:

```
if key == pynput.keyboard._win32.KeyCode.z:
```

Replacing it with either 'z' or "'z'" or just z also doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
def on_press(key):
    print(key, "pressed")
    if key == Key.ctrl_l:
        jazz.MidiOut(0x90, 30, 127)
    if key == "'z'":
        jazz.MidiOut(0x90, 60, 127)

def on_release(key):
    print(key, "released")
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False

with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

When LCtrl is pressed the note plays as expected, and it prints `Key.ctrl_l pressed`. When z is pressed, it prints `'z' pressed` but the note doesn't play. To me it doesn't make sense why it wouldn't recognise the keystroke.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: 'z' = Char 122 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if str(key) == "'z'":
```

it was this simple

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap a character around a `KeyCode`

```
>>> type(keyboard._win32.KeyCode.from_char('z'))
<class 'pynput.keyboard._win32.KeyCode'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from pynput.keyboard import KeyCode

if key == KeyCode.from_char('A'):
    print('A')
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) will help people understand the reasons for your code suggestion.